# Why can't I view the Reactive spring response?

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm just starting to learn `Reactive spring`, but instead of connecting database vs. I want to create a simple controller and return repsonse with `Mono.just()`.

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public Mono<MessageResponse<InstructionListResponse>> test() {
        return Mono.just(
                MsgResponseBuilder.build(true, InstructionListResponse.builder()
                        .instructionList(List.of(InstructionListType.builder()
                                .title("example")
                                .build()))
                        .build())
        );
    }
```

I don't see any response when I request the controls structure in this way.

But ,

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public Flux<String> test() {
        return Flux.just(
                "example1" , "example2"
        );
    }
```

When I do as above, I see example1 and example2 written in postman response.

I don't understand why it's like this? What path should I follow.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "I don't see any response" ? What http status you get, are there any errors in the response/application's logs and etc.?

Comment: @kerbermeister There are no errors in the logs, I get a success 200 on postman